# I want to know the proof of the definite integral :

Tags: definite-integrals

$$ \int _{0}^{\infty }\frac {x^{p-1}dx}{1+x}=\frac {\pi }{\sin(p\pi )}$$ for $0<p<1$.

Please do let me know the proof of this specified integral.

Comment: Have you tried using contours in the complex plane?

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) , we have the Beta Function, its relation with the Gamma Function and [Euler's Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function):

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{ x^{p-1}}{1+x}dx= B(p,1-p)=\frac{\Gamma(p)\Gamma(1-p)}{\Gamma(1)}=\frac\pi{\sin \pi p}$$

Comment: Yeah,  i know that this equation corresponds to Euler's Reflection Formula. But In lieu of deducing this specified reflection formula i came across with this particular definite integral and for that matters i want to know the proof of that specified definite integral which is of course a standard result i presume. So, if u know then do comment down bellow.

Comment: @SayandipBanerjee Well, as commented already: perhaps with complex analysis. Do you know that?

Comment: I haven't started that though but if u can tell me the approach den i could try solving it.....